# How to make argument checking loop in csh

Tags: csh

I try to make script in c-shell which is checking if it is called with -g or -h arguments. If it is called with some other argument it should simply echo "Wrong argument". The problem is that when I run script with -s etc my r value isn't True and I have "if: no file name" error in console. Here's my loop:

```
foreach a ($argv)
    if (( $a == '-h' ) || ( $a == '--help' )) then
        set h=True
    else if (( $a == '-q' ) || ( $a == '--quiet' )) then
        set q=True
    else
        set r=True
    endif
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out I need to put "$a" and i.e. "-h" into "". So the code looks like this now:

```
foreach a ($argv)
    if (( "$a" == "-h" ) || ( "$a" == "--help" )) then
        set h=True
    else if (( "$a" == "-q" ) || ( "$a" == "--quiet" )) then
        set q=True
    else
        set r=True
    endif
end
```

I hope it will help someone.

Comment: foreach: Words not parenthesized.